# For loop in a dictionary inside a dictionary for dataframe construction in herepy (PlacesAPI)

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, for-loop, herepy

I am using Python and I am trying to access the result of function PlacesAPI where I can see supermarkets around me and create a dataframe with few parts of each dictionary inside the main dictionary using a for loop, however I am getting the same information for different rows.

Can you please help me to put each different parts of dictionary in a different row?

Here is my code and the result (now reproducible):

```
    from herepy import PlacesApi
    import pandas as pd

def dataframe():

    a = {'items': [{'title': 'Marcos Francisco dos Santos Padaria e Mercearia',
   'id': 'here:pds:place:07675crc-dfd72cbf57bd45cc9277ed8530ffd61b',
   'ontologyId': 'here:cm:ontology:supermarket',
   'resultType': 'place',
   'address': {'label': 'Marcos Francisco dos Santos Padaria e Mercearia, Rua Oswero Carmo Vilaça, 33, Petrópolis - RJ, 25635-101, Brazil',
    'countryCode': 'BRA',
    'countryName': 'Brazil',
    'stateCode': 'RJ',
    'state': 'Rio de Janeiro',
    'city': 'Petrópolis',
    'district': 'Petrópolis',
    'street': 'Rua Oswero Carmo Vilaça',
    'postalCode': '25635-101',
    'houseNumber': '33'},
   'position': {'lat': -22.5315, 'lng': -43.16904},
   'access': [{'lat': -22.5314, 'lng': -43.16914}],
   'distance': 134,
   'categories': [{'id': '600-6300-0066', 'name': 'Grocery', 'primary': True},
    {'id': '600-6300-0244', 'name': 'Bakery & Baked Goods Store'}],
   'contacts': [{'phone': [{'value': '+552422312493'}]}]},
  {'title': 'Mr. Frango',
   'id': 'here:pds:place:076jx7ps-7c214f50052f0c23c9e5422ebde7d3cd',
   'ontologyId': 'here:cm:ontology:supermarket',
   'resultType': 'place',
   'address': {'label': 'Mr. Frango, Rua Teresa, Petrópolis - RJ, 25635-530, Brazil',
    'countryCode': 'BRA',
    'countryName': 'Brazil',
    'stateCode': 'RJ',
    'state': 'Rio de Janeiro',
    'city': 'Petrópolis',
    'district': 'Petrópolis',
    'street': 'Rua Teresa',
    'postalCode': '25635-530'},
   'position': {'lat': -22.52924, 'lng': -43.17222},
   'access': [{'lat': -22.52925, 'lng': -43.1722}],
   'distance': 545,
   'categories': [{'id': '600-6300-0066', 'name': 'Grocery', 'primary': True},
    {'id': '600-6000-0061', 'name': 'Convenience Store'}],
   'references': [{'supplier': {'id': 'core'}, 'id': '1159487213'}],
   'contacts': [{'phone': [{'value': '+552422201010'},
      {'value': '+552422315720', 'categories': [{'id': '600-6000-0061'}]}]}]},
  {'title': 'Mercadinho Flor de Petrópolis',
   'id': 'here:pds:place:07675crc-6b03dfbac65a45c0bfc52ab9a3f04556',
   'ontologyId': 'here:cm:ontology:supermarket',
   'resultType': 'place',
   'address': {'label': 'Mercadinho Flor de Petrópolis, Rua Teresa, 2060, Petrópolis - RJ, 25635-530, Brazil',
    'countryCode': 'BRA',
    'countryName': 'Brazil',
    'stateCode': 'RJ',
    'state': 'Rio de Janeiro',
    'city': 'Petrópolis',
    'district': 'Petrópolis',
    'street': 'Rua Teresa',
    'postalCode': '25635-530',
    'houseNumber': '2060'},
   'position': {'lat': -22.52895, 'lng': -43.17233},
   'access': [{'lat': -22.52895, 'lng': -43.17219}],
   'distance': 574,
   'categories': [{'id': '600-6300-0066',
     'name': 'Grocery',
     'primary': True}]}]}


    value = []
    address = []
    latlong = []
    
    
    teste  =  pd.DataFrame(columns = ['nome','endereco','rua','numero',
                'cidade','estado','cep','lat','long','raio'])
    
    teste['nome'] = []    
    teste['endereco'] = [] 
    teste['rua'] = []
    teste['numero'] =[]
    teste['cidade'] = [] 
    teste['estado'] = []
    teste['cep'] = []
    teste['lat'] = []
    teste['long'] = []
    teste['raio'] = [] 
        
    
    g = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a.values())
       
    h =[]
    
    for i in range(3):
        v = g[i].values[0]
        h = v.items()
        for k, l in  h:
                value.append(l)
        for c, d in value[4].items():
                address.append(d)
        for la, lo in value[5].items():
                latlong.append(lo)  
        novo_concorrente = {'nome': value[0], 'endereco':address[0], 
                           'rua':address[7], 'numero':address[9], 
                           'cidade':address[5], 'estado':address[3], 
                           'cep':address[8],'lat':latlong[0],
                           'long':latlong[1],'raio':value[7]}
    
        teste = teste.append(novo_concorrente, ignore_index=True)
        
    return teste
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is great that you (almost) provided a reproducible use case. I would say it would be easier for you to get help if you make it 100% reproducible. You could start by removing the "getting Places API response" code, since it is probably not relevant. Then put all the code to create the DataFrame in a single code block including the `a` variable declaration. Put it in a `.py` file and run it until you make sure it reproduces your use case. As it is right now, it seems you even have some indentation problems in your code. ;-)

Comment: Hey Peque ! Yes, I had problem to put the code here in my first question, however my original code is not indented like this. I put everything inside a function and now it is reproducible, Can you please try it?

Comment: You can update your question with the reproducible code. Also, you may want to take this opportunity to see if you can simplify the code while still getting the same results.

Comment: I just updated the question, thank you for the highlighted points, I am new here and it is great to have someone helping at this firts stage !

Comment: You may want to focus your attention in the `for` loop. Add a `print(value[0])` statement and look at the output. Is that what you expect? Does it give you an idea on how you would need to update or access the `value` variable instead? ;-)

Comment: Actually as you said, the focus is in the for loop, I think the 3rd and 4th for should be inside de 2nd for, as I need to access values inside the first directory and I am stuck because it is raising errors when I put the for inside.
I just need few information and I could find a way to map them, but I don't know how to access a value of a directory inside a directory with a loop.
Anyway, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should focus on your `for` loop. I would suggest you to create a dictionary for each row you want to define in your final DataFrame, and then create a list to append those dictionaries to.

In example:

```
rows = []
for item in a["items"]:
    row = {
        "Latitude": item["position"]["lat"],
        "Postal code": item["address"]["postalCode"],
    }
    rows.append(row)

result = DataFrame(rows)
result
```

Hope it helps as a starting point.

Comment: Hey Peque, Thank you so much for your support !! I just organized things I want from the enide dictionary and I am able to get almost all of them which is great !! I am just facing problem to access the "houseNumber" string I don't know why.. anyway I am going to check further

Comment: @MarianeSantos For the data you provided, `houseNumber` seems to be non-mandatory. You can get values of a dictionary when you don't know if the key exists. Have a look at the [`.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get) and use a fallback value.